# why doesn't the outlet of this nested ember route display?

Tags: ember.js

there are two routes here, section A and section B. section B has a nested route called subsectionB.

when you click "go to subsection B" it should display 
SECTION B
==>SUB SECTION B

but nothing happens. the section A content remains. the logging in the RouteManager says its transitioning, but the outlet doesn't get updated. what's wrong?

here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/inconduit/hSpHK/2/

and below i have pasted the app code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  App = Ember.Application.create({
    ready: function() {
      App.initialize();
    }
  });

  App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();
  App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend({
      templateName: "application_view"
  });

  App.SectionAController = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
  App.SectionAView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "section_a_view"
  });

  App.SectionBController = Ember.ObjectController.extend();
  App.SectionBView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "section_b_view"
  });

  App.SubSectionB = Ember.ArrayController.extend();
  App.SubSectionBView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: "sub_section_b_view"
  })

  App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({

    enableLogging: true,

    root: Ember.Route.extend({        

      doSectionA    : function(router, event) { console.log('blah'); router.transitionTo('sectionA.index'); },
      doSubSectionB  : function(router, event) { router.transitionTo('sectionB.subSectionB.index'); },

      index: Ember.Route.extend({
          route: '/',
          redirectsTo: "sectionA.index"
      }),

      sectionA: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/sectionA',
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
          route: '/',
          connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('sectionA');
          }
        })
      }),

      sectionB: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/sectionB',
        index: Ember.Route.extend({
          route: '/',
          connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('sectionB');
          }
        }),
        subSectionB: Ember.Route.extend({
          route: '/subSectionB',
          index: Ember.Route.extend({
              route: '/',
              connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
                router.get('sectionBController').connectOutlet('subSectionB');
              }
          })
        })

      })

    })
  })
</script>
</head>
<body>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application_view">
  <a href="#" {{action "doSectionA"}}>go to section A</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" {{action "doSubSectionB"}}>go to subsection B</a>
    <div class="container">
        {{outlet}}
    </div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="section_a_view">
    SECTION A
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="section_b_view">
    SECTION B
    {{outlet}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="sub_section_b_view">
    this is sub section B
  </script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the log of the router when you click "go to subsection B":

```
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'doSubSectionB' to state root. 
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.sectionB
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.sectionB.subSectionB
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.sectionB.subSectionB.index
```

The router never passes through `root.sectionB.index` which loads the template for sectionB (which in turn includes the outlet for subSectionB). Therefore you need to ensure that the template for sectionB is loaded by placing it into the `root.sectionB` route:

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ppanagi/hSpHK/4/

```
sectionB: Ember.Route.extend({
   route: '/sectionB',
   connectOutlets: function(router, context) {
      router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('sectionB');
   },      

   index: Ember.Route.extend({
       route: '/',           
   }),

   // ...
})
```

Comment: thank you very much, i'm just learning the router now and did not know how to read the routing log properly.